# This is the first time

Tags: conversation

I'm eating sushi. I tell my friends, who has invited me to eat it,

> This is the first time I've eaten sushi.

I think this is wrong, because I'm still in the process of eating sushi. Using present perfect doesn't seem to work.

> This is the first time I'm eating sushi.

I think this is right, because I'm still eating.

> I'm eating sushi for the first time.

I think this is also correct.

What would you think?

Comment: Asking "is this correct" is off-topic for this site. Your question must be about learning English. Why do you think each is right or wrong, and what is the difficulty you have in understanding what you have found?

Comment: This seems the same as https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/319309/ive-never-eaten-thai-food-before There's not really any difference between the two cases, although possibly you don't realise that.

Comment: Yes, due to my poor English, I fail to realize that. Could you explain it?

Comment: *I think this is wrong, because I'm still in the process of eating sushi.* - but "I have" is the present tense, so...

Comment: _This is the first time I've eaten sushi_ sounds perfectly natural to me, though it may seem illogical to you. (If the meal is still in progress, you _have already eaten_ some of the food!)

Comment: But "I've eaten sushi" normally means "I've finished eating it". Isn't it so?

Comment: @Stephen Not really.  *I have been to Australia* means that I have travelled to Australia at some point in my life, but it does not mean that I am finished with Australia.  The present perfect is just not as "specific" as that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I've never eaten Thai food before](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/319309/ive-never-eaten-thai-food-before)

Answer (score 1):

All three are grammatically correct, and would convey the intention you're trying to put out in this context.

> Using present perfect doesn't seem to work.

As for this, using present perfect here is normal. Even if you're still eating sushi, you have already eaten some of it, even if it is just one bite. So technically, you have already tried sushi when you're having a second bite. Similar explanations to this have already been provided in the comments by users @Kate Bunting and @stangdon.

Comment: To make it even clearer, *before* eating a singe bite, you could use either the second or the third sentence, but not the first (since you haven't eaten sushi yet), but after you've eaten a bite, the first sentence makes perfect sense.